# I cannot display a page of my website, i tried debugging Uncaught Syntax Error 1: import { useState } from 'react'

Tags: javascript, import, syntax-error, use-state, display

A page on my site is not showing on my localhost. I do not understand why.

The Home page is displayed correctly :

[J'arrive bien à afficher l'index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRpZN.png)

but when i click  Sell Digital Asset it doesn't work... Nothing is displayed,
we just have the header :

[Just the header like the home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og3zf.png)

when I do a debug on `create-item.js` (the file of the page i want display) it gives me this :

```sh
    /usr/local/bin/node ./pages/create-item.js
Process exited with code 1
Uncaught SyntaxError ...(personal information)/pages/create-item.js:1
import { useState } from 'react'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1032:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
```

Does someone have an idea ?
thank you

Regards,
Max

Comment: It looks like you're statically serving React source code? I.e. no webpack in between? Please explain exactly how you're building this. It looks like node and express?

Comment: thanks for your comment ! yes it is with node...

Answer (score 0):

Add to your package.json:

```json
"type": "module"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).